# how do i echo a row with quotationmarks in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

does anyone of you know how i can echo this `" echo $row['time']; "` in quotation marks.

The print should look like "XYZ"

I need this for my own JSON style which will be used in an app..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can print quotation marks via `'"'` or `"\""`. Also, in case you didn't know, there is a function [`json_encode`](http://de2.php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concate `""` using in echo as

```
 echo '"'.$row['time'].'"';
```

Comment: thats means $row['time'] is null and there is nothing to print. First to var_dump($row['time']) and see if there is some data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print json_encode($row['time']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Probably want this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
if($result){
$rows = array();
$count = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if($count > 0){
  $i = 0;
  while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[$i]['time'] = $r['time'];
$i++;
  }
echo json_encode(array('data' => $rows)); 
}
```

Above code will give you something like,

```
{
"data": [
    {
       "time": "first row time"
    },
    {
       "time": "second row time"
    }
   ]
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also *escape* " within a "-delimited string:

```
echo "\"$row['time']\"";
```

Thnx for the heads-up on the extra ;. Now, what is the syntax error? Is it the ' around time, or something else? It's very possible that some PHPs will not like trying to interpolate an array element inside a string, and you'll have to go to concatenation.

Comment: `echo "\"{$row['time']}\"";`  Your post has a syntax error and a semicolon which doesn't belong there